# Why is Insert > Related List not working in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, webpart-connection

Hi I have got a few lists with Lookup fields from Source lists. I wish to have a Related lists (Webpart connections from 2007 days) where I select item from master and then child records are displayed. Although I have followed the instructions on the below article, the "relationship" bit is not working. The Related records from the child lists are not filtering rather showing all records from the child table.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-HA102771358.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I also encountered this issue, and the solution is pretty simple, but not very obvious. When creating a new page, you MUST be sure that you create a page of type **Web Part Page**. When you use the default "Add a Page" option from the site settings menu, the default page type is a *Wiki page*, not a web part page. Even though you can add web parts to a Wiki page, the Wiki page does not include the functionality for implementing web part connections.

Once I created a page using one of the Web Part Page types, I was able to use web part connections.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this:

1. Browse to the affected page, and then open the page in **edit mode**.
2. Click the **drop-down arrow** in the **upper-right corner of the Web Part** for the tasks list, and then click **Edit Web Part**.
3. On the right side of the page in the Web Part properties controls, click the plus sign (+) on the **Miscellaneous section**, click to select the **Server Render checkbox**, and then click OK.
4. Save the changes to the page.

source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2924913